# Which one of the following vectors in R^3 is a unit vector that is parallel to the plane with general equation 2x+2y+z=1?

Tags: vector-spaces

Which one of the following vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a unit vector that is parallel to the plane with general equation $2x+2y+z=1$?

$$a) (2/3, -1/3, -2/3) $$
$$b) (-3, 2, 2)$$
$$c) (2/3, 2/3, -1/3)$$
$$d) (1/2, 1/2, 1/\sqrt{2})$$

Would I be correct in choosing a) as the magnitude of the vector is $1$ and the dot product of $(2/3, -1/3, -2/3)$ and the normal vector to the plane is $0$?

Answer (score 1):

Technically you are completely right. However your approach seems a bit artificial to me, since you first find a vector which is perpendicular to the plane and then check whether a vector is perpendicular to this vector.

More directly you can see that every vector *parallel* to the plane must actually be *in* the plane after translation. Hence it must satisfy
$$2x+2y+z=0.$$

Comment: On the other hand, "first find a vector which is perpendicular to the plane" is quite trivial, because that vector is exactly what the coefficients in the plane's equation are.

Comment: Sure, saying that a vector satisfies $2x+2y+z=0$ is virtually the same as saying that it is orthogonal to $(2,2,1)^T$, so the effort is the same. All I am saying is that that the reasoning appears to be a bit intricate.

Comment: x @Simon: Not significantly more intricate than imagining the equation for a translated plane, in my immediate opinion.

Comment: Actually, if you try to prove that the normal vector is given as $(2,2,1)^T$ you do exactly that. But maybe this is just the way I think about it and most certainly it is a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes.
Since the vector is perpendicular to the normal (which is itself perpendicular to the plane) and we are in $\mathbb{R^3}$ it must be parallel to the plane. The only other vector this works for is b) which isn't a unit vector. So yes you are correct.